# Etat HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee

I want to display a list of `CoursChange` using `web service`; in the `console` the list displays correctly but is not the case in the web service.

the URL of `web service` is http://localhost:8383/MyApplication/rest/coursChangeService/cours

How can I display it? where is my error?

think you for helping me.

### WebService

```
@Component
@Path("/coursChangeService")
public class DebiteurWs {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("coursChangeBusiness")
CoursChangeBusiness coursChangeBusiness;
@Path("/cours")
@GET
public CoursChange[] getAllCours() {
    List<CoursChange> listCours = coursChangeBusiness.listCoursChange();


    CoursChange[] liste =new CoursChange[listCours.size()];;

    for(int i = 0 ; i<listCours.size() ; i++)
    {
        liste[i]= listCours.get(i);
        System.out.println(liste[i]);
    }



    return liste;
}
```

Comment: 500 error just means an exception was thrown. Usually, a good exception is already the whole answer at its own (and otherwise quite googlable if you're incapable to interpret it). Only. the exception is entirely missing in your question, so we can't translate it for you in layman's terms.

Comment: I put that error because any exception was dispalyed on the console, otherwise i put it.   when running the web service , the query and the list of   the CoursChange display on the console . that's all.

Comment: Then you've another problem. Exceptions are being swallowed somehow (perhaps a badly configured logger?). I suggest to take a step back and fix that first so you get a normal exception trace so you can advance with normal research on the 500 error.